# Laravel: Add field from view on (USER: Mass Assignable Attribute)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my `User.php`  for `Mass Assignable`

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'contact_no', 'is_blocked', 'on_hold', 'wallet_bal', 'is_admin'
];
```

Currently these fields are coming from my Table: `users`

Now I'm planning to add one field but not coming from the `users` but from a `view table` named as `userbal`

View: `userBal`

[image]

and I'm trying to add the `total_balance` field of a user. Is there any trick to do that?

My Table Structure

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what the question is? is view your table structure?

Comment: I updated my question, you can check my structure now

Comment: You mean, you want to get values of `userbal` using `userId`?

Comment: The solution already exists here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593270/how-to-access-db-views-using-laravel-models

Comment: I just want to include the `total_balance` from userBal and put it in the fillable. Where the fillable fields is coming from users is that even possible?

Comment: Got the solution thanks Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution already exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593270/how-to-access-db-views-using-laravel-models).

*(answered in the comments by @Gabriel)*